# Django Exporting selected ListView Items To csv file

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a list View which I want to select certain rows of the records returned and write them out to a csv file (which can later be imported to Excel).

The problem is when I call the function to do the export via the button on the list View, I cant seem to get which items (choices) were selected.  I am attemting to get them via the request object.

Here is a look at the model, views, and templates I am trying to use. See below:

[image: List CD's Template]

```
class Cd(models.Model):
  artist_name    = models.CharField(max_length=155)
  cd_title       = models.CharField(max_length=155)
  cd_total_time           = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00")
  cd_total_time_delta     = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  cd_run_time         = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  cd_run_time_delta   = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)
  cd_remaining_time       = models.TimeField(default="00:00:00",blank=True)
  cd_remaining_time_delta = models.DurationField(default=timedelta)

views.py
class List_Cds(ListView):
    model = Cd
    template_name = 'list_cds.html'

def export_to_csv(request):
    choices = request.GET.getlist('choices')
    print("In export_to_csv choices selected were: %s" % choices)
    cd_export = Cd.objects.filter(id__in=choices)
    response = HttpResponse('text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition']= 'attachment; filename=cdlist.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Artist', 'Cd Title', 'CD Run Time'])
    cd_fields = cd_export.values_list('artist_name','cd_title', 'cd_total_time')
    for cd in cd_fields:
        writer.writerow(cd_fields)
    return response

list_cds.html
    . . . 
{% block content %}
<br>
    <button type="submit" value="listbatchview" onclick="location.href='{% url 'export_to_csv' %}'">Batch Export CSV</button>
    <TABLE id="list_table">
      <TR BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
        <TD></TD>
        <TD></TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center">Artist Name</TD>
        <TD ALIGN="Center">Cd Name</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="99CCFF" ALIGN="Center">Cd Length</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#CC99CC" ALIGN="Center">Run time</TD>
        <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="Center">Remaining Time</TD>
      </TR>
      {% for cd in object_list %}
        <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <TR BGCOLOR="#B0B0FF">
          <TD ALIGN="Center" rowspan="1" height="33" width="33">
                  <input type="checkbox" value="{{cd.pk }}" name="form.choices">
          <TD ALIGN="Center" rowspan="1" height="33" width="33">
            <A href="{% url 'cd_update' cd.pk %}">
              <IMG SRC="{% static 'images/edit.gif' %}">
            </A>
          </TD>
          <TD ALIGN="CENTER">{{ cd.artist_name|truncatechars:30 }}</TD>
          <TD ALIGN="CENTER">{{ cd.cd_title }}</TD>
          <TD BGCOLOR="#99CCFF" ALIGN="CENTER">{{ cd.cd_total_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
          <TD BGCOLOR="#CC99CC" ALIGN="CENTER">{{ cd.cd_run_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
          {% if cd.cd_run_time_delta > cd.cd_total_time_delta %}
            <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="CENTER">&nbsp;(-{{ cd.cd_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }})</TD>
          {% else %}
            <TD BGCOLOR="#8DF1BF" ALIGN="CENTER">&nbsp;{{ cd.cd_remaining_time|time:"H:i:s" }}</TD>
          {% endif %}
        </TR>
      {% endfor %}
    </TABLE>
{% endblock content %}

forms.py
class BatchListForm(forms.Form):
    choices = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
            )
```

The file get generated, but only the header lines are in the file, and the output on the server shows no choices:

```
March 09, 2023 - 12:29:05
Django version 3.2.12, using settings 'cd_library.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
In export_to_csv choices selected were: []
[09/Mar/2023 12:29:21] "GET /export_to_csv/ HTTP/1.1" 200 37
```

Can anyone help me with how do this this correctly?